# Subdomain took over "normal" domain in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I set up a subdomain test.example.com and got it running, but now when I go to example.com, it points to test.example.com's directory. In other words, instead of going to /var/www/html it points to /var/www/test

I haven't altered httpd.conf other than adding this at the very bottom for the subdomain:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.example.com
    ServerAlias test.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/test/"
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I fix httpd.conf so the normal domain points to /var/www/html and the subdomain continues to point to /var/www/test ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when using virtual hosting, the "main host goes away". See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html , specifically the note "Main host goes away".

So, in your case, simply duplicate your VirtualHost container and configure it for a ServerName of www.example.com with a DocumentRoot of /var/www/html .

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only vhost that you have configured then this is expected behaviour. Apache will serve up the requested domain or the default domain. Without an explicit default/catch-all domain the first vhost that apache processes is served.

If you want to serve up example.com you need to create a vhost for it

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
</VirtualHost>
```

and then restart the httpd service.